# Custom search: by post data and post metadata?

Tags: custom-field, search

I'm struggling with a WordPress search function. Maybe it will just help if someone can explain to me how the built in WordPress function works. But here's what I want:

- Two search fields, by name and by location
- The first field should check all the common post data (only posts) + categories
- The second field should only check on the posts custom fields
- Only one field needs to be filled

First of all, is this even possible or do I have to use native php+sql? If it is possible, can you please give me a hint on where to start?

Answer (score 6):

The built-in WP search looks **only** a Posts'/Pages' Title and Content, **not** thru other elements like Custom Fields and the content of Shortcodes. There's a number of plugs that will search Custom Fields:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/

There also a filter `apply_filters_ref_array()` that "allows plugins to contextually add/remove/modify the search section of the database query."

FYI, the search is defined in `query.php`, and looks like:

`...if ( !empty($q['s']) ) 
...
($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')`

So title and content are the only things in the default search.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the search by making your own search template, and using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query). In most cases there are enough parameters to do what you want, you won't need to dive into the database.

Example: [creating a custom search template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page).

If you do need something outside of what WP_Query can do, you don't need to bust out custom php/sql you can use WordPress's WPDB class to [interact with the database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class).

Answer (score -2):

I have a solution to this problem is very simple:

Open up your `search.php` file, paste this code on the top of your search file.

```
function the_acf_search_func( $sql ){
    global $wpdb;
    $the_acf_search = get_query_var( 'the_acf_search' );
    global $s;
    if( $the_acf_search ){
            $rep = $wpdb->prepare( ") OR ( CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%s' )  OR (",   '%'.$s.'%' );
            $sql = str_replace(') OR (',$rep,$sql);
    }
    return $sql;
}
add_action( 'posts_where', 'the_acf_search_func' );
// var_dump($paged);die();
$args = array_merge( (array)$wp_query->query_vars, array(
    'posts_per_page'=>999999,
    // 'paged '=>$p, 
    'the_acf_search'=>$s, 
    'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'value' => '',
           'compare' => '!=',
       )
   ) 
));
```

Also blogged this a little early for a better understanding... http://www.jqui.net/wordpress/wp-search-custom-fields/

hope it helps.