# Wp eCommerce meta information search

Tags: search, plugin-wp-e-commerce

Out of the box, WP eCommerce does not support Meta search. This is a big problem if you are selling books online and need clients to be able to search by the most important Meta tag, Author!

Can someone please tell me how I could go about including the meta information search or is there a better plugin that does not cost an arm and a leg to search for meta information too?

Many thanks

Comment: Duplicate or similar to another question. Link provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a duplicate question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7651/custom-search-by-post-data-and-post-metadata) that has a number of suggestions and references to plugins that will help.